# React require(state) not working

Tags: image, reactjs, module, state, require

So, i have my react component, that basically loads an image.

This works fine:

```
<a><img id='cog' src={require('1.png')} onClick={this.handleClick}/></a>
```

This doesn't:

```
this.state = {
image: '1.png'
};

<a><img id='cog' src={require(this.state.image)} onClick={this.handleClick}/></a>
```

Returns "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '1.jpg'."

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where do you set your initial state ? In constructor , right ?

Comment: yes, in the constructor, sry i just put the important part of the code

Comment: you shouldn't need require should you? just `{this.state.image}` should suffice

Comment: It gives you an error for 1.jpg but you set the state to be 1.png. Are you sure you have not used 1.jpg anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Hui you may use `require("./"+url)`
the variable url must contains only the the name of file
Have a good day